# Spring MVC to Spring Webflux migration - block vs subscribe

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's imagine a scenario where there's an old app written using Servlet stack and you decide to migrate it to a Spring Webflux. Let's also say that first thing to migrate is `RestTemplate` to `WebClient`.

What would be preferred way of handling `Mono` or `Flux` that `WebClient` returns? Calling `block` seems okay solution since app uses `RestTemplate` which blocks anyway. `subscribe` should be a bit nicer since it has a callback, but maybe you have to wait to be able to continue. Also, with `subscribe`, do we need to handle a `Disposable` and, if yes, how, because I'm not sure where is the best place to call `dispose` on it?

And one more question regarding JDBC. How dangerous is to use `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`? From my understanding, having a separate thread pool should help especially if Netty is used. It's not ideal, but could it be a temporary solution until R2DBC drivers reach 1.0.0? What if app uses Tomcat? Is the situation better since Tomcat by default has more threads?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What would be preferred way of handling Mono or Flux that WebClient returns?

Given you're aiming to use Webflux, the ultimate *preferred* way is to deal with these publishers the *entire* way up your reactive chain. This means you won't end up calling subscribe on anything directly, because your controller will itself return a `Mono` (and everything, including the `WebClient` calls, will just be incorporated into that `Mono` via a series of reactive opreations in the chain.)

However, as you point out, you can't realistically migrate everything at once.

If it's *only* the `WebClient` that you're migrating for now, then just call `block()` to treat it the same way as your `RestController`. There's no advantage with calling `subscribe()` and then waiting for the subscription to complete - that's just a less obvious and more long-winded way of blocking.

Once you migrate more and more of your stack to reactive, you can do more and more in a reactive fashion, and then start to "move" your `block()` calls further up the chain as a result (until the block is at the controller level, and then you can just switch over to returning the `Mono`.)

> Also, with subscribe, do we need to handle a Disposable

Only if you need to potentially cancel the subscriber (and it supports it.) This is quite a rare occurance in my experience.

> And one more question regarding JDBC. How dangerous is to use `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`?

`boundedElastic()` is designed to be a wrapper for blocking IO, so there's nothing inherently wrong with using that on the reactor side. The only "danger" would be on the JDBC / app side as to if it fits your requirements:

- It's capped at 10x the number of CPU cores
- The number of "queued" tasks is capped at 100K

If you've got enough long running DB queries that this isn't enough, then you might consider using `newBoundedElastic()` instead and specifying the `threadCap` and `queuedTaskCap` manually.

> What if app uses Tomcat? Is the situation better since Tomcat by default has more threads?

I wouldn't advise relying on it. Tomcat still uses one thread per request (even with Webflux), so the danger there is you end up blocking on a thread you shouldn't, and end up not realising and then relying on that behaviour (which would then all come tumbling down when you switched to Netty.)

Comment: That's such a nicely written response :) Also, you've basically confirmed every theory I had, but was not able to find a proper answer/confirmation.
I have 2 years of experience with RxJava so reactive is not new to me, but I found too many places where it says that JDBC + reactive can cause a lot of issues which was weird to me since I know about `boundedElastic()`.
But, I guess there is trade off. Maybe you'll encounter some issue with calling blocking APIs and might be better off sticking with Tomcat (since it still works with reactive types), but I guess that depends on the use-case.

Comment: This is one of those "hall of fame" answers when it comes to reactive java. I'm a complete beginner to WebFlux, learning about it bit by bit and this answer really serves the purpose of confirming my notions about WebFlux and reactive java. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerry  in standart webmvc can I use subscribe for async call ,it is working.Only thing when thread finish and subscribe method make call and finish call is it disposed?

Comment: @Bilgehan You can, you don't need to worry about disposing / cleanup, but the big disadvantage is that there's then no way to get a callback when it's complete to "chain" it to any other operation. So it's truly "fire and forget" in that sense. If that's genuinely what you need then there's no issue in subscribing, but more often than not you'll want some kind of feedback after completion, and in that case it's not suitable.

Comment: Thanks Michael, then it is completely safe, if i use webclient in simple mvc with subscribe for async calls or do you suggest Any other approach? As i read spring site, they suggest webclient for rest and asyctemplate

Comment: I can't say it's completely safe without taking a much deeper look, but if you genuinely just want a complete "fire and forget" type strategy with no feedback when anything has completed (or gone wrong), then sure, I can't see an issue with it in principle.